# Custom certificate validation in WCF service

Tags: wcf, security, iis, certificate

I want to check client certificates in my WCF service.

My goal is to allow only clients with certificates with specific thumbprints to be able to communicate with my service.

My WCF service is hosted in IIS, I'm using basicHttpBinding and security mode="transport" with credential type "Certificate". IIS requires client certificates for communication with the service.

Thanks in advance for help.

UPDATE:
My configuration:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding 
             name="testBinding"
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
         <readerQuotas 
                    maxDepth="2147483647"
                maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
 <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/> 
             </security>

</binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Behavior:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SomeServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom" customCertificateValidatorType="SomeService.CustomCertificateValidator,SomeService"  />
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>         
     </behavior> 
   </serviceBehaviors>
```

Service configuration:

```
<service 
               behaviorConfiguration="SomeServiceBehavior"
               name="SomeService">
        <endpoint 
                  address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="testBinding"
                  contract="ISomeService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
```

And for test purpose I implemented validator in this way:

```
public class CustomCertificateValidator : X509CertificateValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 certificate)
        {                
            throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("TEST Certificate was not issued by a trusted issuer TEST");
        }
    }
```

And this doesn't work. I can connect to my service with any valid certificate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a class derived from X509CertificateValidator and use it to do custom validation of the incoming certificate. Throw an SecurityTokenValidationException if you want to fail validation for some reason.

Set the certificateValidationMode to Custom and specify your validator in the clientCertificate service behavior section of the config file.

[How to: Create a Service that Employs a Custom Certificate Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733806.aspx)

Comment: I tried to add custom validator in clientCertificate but it doesn't work. It seems that it is designed to validate client certificate that the service will be using in duplex mode. I need to validate incoming certificate (certificate the client is sending). Have you tried this option in this scenario?

Comment: This can work on either the client or service side and is used to validate the incoming message certificate.

Comment: Make sure you add this to the <serviceBehaviors> to validate the client in the service which is what you want. The <endpointBehaviors> is used only on the client to validate the service.

Comment: I've added my configuration. Do you need any more information?

Comment: The part of the config you added seems correct. However you didn't add your actual service configuration. so please check if you are actually using "SomeServiceBehavior" with your service. It's happened to me quit a few times that I create a service behavior but forgot to add it to my service.

Comment: Just noticed you are using transport instead if message level security. For this to work you need to use message level security instead.

Comment: I've posted my service configuration. I think that behaviorConfiguration is set correctly. What else could be the problem? At first, I tried to configure it on iis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559213/wcf-is-it-possible-to-disable-anonymous-access-in-iis-and-have-service-over-htt but it also doesn't work. Is there any other way to access cerificate sent by the client and check it? Or maybe there is something wrong with my configuration/code?

Comment: And is it possible to use message level security over https?

Comment: You can use TransportWithMessageCredential as the security mode. This uses a combination of HTTPS with message security.

Comment: When I change it to this value I get: The SSL settings for the service 'None' does not match those of the IIS 'Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert".

Comment: Did you add <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/> and remove the <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/> ?

Comment: yes, it looks like this:
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">      
          <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
</security>

Comment: In IIS anonymous access is allowed, no other checkboxes are checked in that window. In communication windows require SSL is checked and require client certificates is chosen. Certificate mapping is not checked. I don't know exact names of these fields / windows because it is not english version of iis.

Comment: I also cannot find any mex bindings in my configuration that some people point as the reason of the problem.

Comment: In IIS you should not have anything checked about the client supplying certificates. The client certificate should be part of the message, if not WCF will not receive the certificate and IIS is doing the client validation.

Answer (score 6):

I do NOT think there is anyway to have 'Custom Certificate Validation' with 'Transport Security'. It only works with 'Message Security'.

Comment: Not true.  I have custom certificate validation running in transport mode

Answer (score 1):

YES, you can use basicHttpBinding with security set to Transport and you need to hook to the ServiceHost creation in IIS  - see [Custom Service Host](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx). 
You should be able to validate thumbprint values, certificates or any other data if you create custom config section to define list of validation criteria.

Sample code for the implementation of all of the above is available in the code download from [this CodeProject artticle](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcfcertificates.aspx).