# WCF custom certificate validation with BasicHttpBinding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-security

I have a WCF application hosted on IIS 6 that needs to

1. Have 2-way SSL authentication
2. Validate client certificate content with some client host information
3. Validate client certificate is issued by the valid subCA.

I was able to do 1) successfully. I am trying to achieve 2) and 3) by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559915/custom-certificate-validation-in-wcf-service) - basically creating a class that inherits X509CertificateValidator and overriding the Validate method with my own validation implementation(step 2 and 3). I followed the MSDN instructions exactly however, it seem that the Validate method is not being called. I purposely throw a SecurityAccessDeniedException in the overidden Validate method and no exception is thrown when I tried to access the service via my browser.  I can still access my website with any client certificate.

I also read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559915/custom-certificate-validation-in-wcf-service) but it didn't really help. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior"
           name="SampleNameSpace.SampleClass">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
                  contract="SampleNameSpace.ISampleClass" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SimpleServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Default" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom" customCertificateValidatorType="SampleNameSpace.MyX509CertificateValidator, SampleAssembly"/>
          </clientCertificate>
        </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="NewBinding0">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: I am experiencing something similar. In one environment it works, but in another BIG-IP Load Balanced environment it ignores the Validate method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to override certificate validation with this [ServerCertificateValidationCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx)

We are using it with WCF HttpBinding in such way:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
     (sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => 
     {
        var isValid = false;
        // some checking logic
        return isValid;
     };
```