# WCF Service Accepts Any Old Certificate

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I am trying to set up this WCF service to only accept requests when the client presents the "Test 01" certificate. The problem is that it seems to accept any certificate from the same authority, for example "Test 04".

**How do I reject all requests that aren't sent using the "Test 01" certificate?**

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding
      name="TestSecureBinding"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport
          clientCredentialType="Certificate"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>

    <behavior name="TestCertificateBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <certificate
            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
            findValue="Test 01"/>
          <authentication
            certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"
            trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"
            revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  <service
    name="IService"
    behaviorConfiguration="TestCertificateBehavior">
    <endpoint
      name="MyHttps"
      address="https://localhost:443"
      contract="IService"
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="TestSecureBinding">
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://localhost:443"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

Comment: You have to write a custom certificate validator:

[See this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559915/custom-certificate-validation-in-wcf-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to configure this in plain WCF configuration - you have to roll your own.

```
public class CertificateValidator : X509CertificateValidator
{
    private string _expectedSubjectName;

    public CertificateValidator(string expectedSubjectName)
    {
        _expectedSubjectName = expectedSubjectName;
    }

    public override void Validate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        if (certificate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");
        }

        if (certificate.SubjectName.Name != _expectedSubjectName)
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("Invalid certificate");
        }
    }
}
```

Which you then attach to your service host:

```
serviceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = 
                X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom;
serviceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CustomCertificateValidator =
                new CertificateValidator(expectedCertificateName);
```

Taken from: [Creating a service that employs a custom certificate validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733806.aspx).