# How do I validate the client certificate on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, certificate

I have to implement a web service that is called by a predefined third party. The documentation says

> You are responsible for verifying the caller's certificate thumbprint. Only accept calls from certificates that have the correct public key.

and there's a .cer file with their certificate public key.

Now in `HttpRequest` class there's `ClientCertificate` property that presumably holds an `HttpClientCertificate` object that in turn has `PublicKey` property of type `byte[]`.

Suppose I've loaded that .cer file and got another certificate object that also has a public key accessible.

How do I validate the certificate that comes in the request against the one I've loaded? Do I just compare the two public key `byte[]` arrays or do I do anything else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom certificate validation in WCF service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559915/custom-certificate-validation-in-wcf-service)

Comment: @Alex Filipovici: That one is for WCF, I'm inside ASP.NET service.

Answer (score 0):

If you import a certificate in your machine's certificate store, any uses of HTTPs endpoint will automatically be validated by the .NET Framework (WCF, HttpClient, etc).

If it has been issued by a trusted CA, it's even better because then you don't even need to import the certificate.

You do not need to manually verify it.