# How to maintain a secured connection between the client and server?

Tags: c#, security, authentication, https, ssl-certificate

I have designed a desktop application using windows forms app.

It will be receiving a pop-up message whenever an updated version is available on the server.

I have generated an API which consists of the updated version of the desktop application which is been used as the server with the help of the ngrok and I have enabled the SSL for the API. The SSL certificate is been installed into trusted root certification authority.

Now how to use the SSL for server validation(that is the clients who the SSL only need to hit the server and can download the updated version)?

Please, someone help me in solving this issue.

Comment: What about client side certificate + client certificate checking server side?

Comment: Assuming you are using WCF, this could solve your problem [Custom certificate validation in WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559915/custom-certificate-validation-in-wcf-service)

Comment: No, I have not created any client-side certificate. Can you please suggest some articles on this which will guide me in a better manner?

Comment: The answer in the linked question points to a nice doc in learn.microsoft.com named "How to: Create a Service that Employs a Custom Certificate Validator". Check that question & answer and if you find useful that answer upvote it

Comment: Can't we just use the server certificate for restricting the users to hit the server?

Comment: You should server side discriminate/authenticate the diferent client requests, if clients do not provide anything distinctive, how do you plan to distinguish one client from the other? Server side certificate only makes sure the server is who claims to be. If you can emit certificates, client side certificates is one possible solution. There are others ways, like basic authentication, but with only a server side certificate you can not do it.